# Anyway to separate at whitespaces but avoid separating at file paths?

Tags: python, regex, list, split, whitespace

I am trying to separate this string into a list using `regex`:

```py
-y -hwaccel cuda -threads 8 -loglevel error -hide_banner -stats -i - -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc constqp -preset p7 -qp 18 C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Smoothie\test 124\Resampled_vid.mp4
```

I am using the following method to separate it:

```py
split(r'(?!\\)'+'\s+',f"{Settings[1]}".format(Input=InFile,Output=OutFile))

Output:
['-y', '-hwaccel', 'cuda', '-threads', '8', '-loglevel', 'error', '-hide_banner', '-stats', '-i', '-', '-c:v', 'hevc_nvenc', '-rc', 'constqp', '-preset', 'p7', '-qp', '18', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python\\Smoothie\\test', '124\\Resampled_vid.mp4']
```

Desired Output:

```py
['-y', '-hwaccel', 'cuda', '-threads', '8', '-loglevel', 'error', '-hide_banner', '-stats', '-i', '-', '-c:v', 'hevc_nvenc', '-rc', 'constqp', '-preset', 'p7', '-qp', '18', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python\\Smoothie\\test 124\\Resampled_vid.mp4']
```

Is there anyway, I can exclusively avoid splitting at a file path?

Comment: You need a parser, not a regex.

Comment: Is the file path always at the end of the string?

Comment: No it can be anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an `re.findall` approach here:

```py
inp = "-y -hwaccel cuda -threads 8 -loglevel error -hide_banner -stats -i - -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc constqp -preset p7 -qp 18 C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Smoothie\test 124\Resampled_vid.mp4"
parts = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+:(?:\\[^\\]+)+\.\w+|\S+', inp)
print(parts)

['-y', '-hwaccel', 'cuda', '-threads', '8', '-loglevel', 'error', '-hide_banner',
 '-stats', '-i', '-', '-c:v', 'hevc_nvenc', '-rc', 'constqp', '-preset', 'p7',
 '-qp', '18',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python\\Smoothie\test 124\\Resampled_vid.mp4']
```

The regex pattern used here says to match, alternatively:

```regex
[A-Z]+:(?:\\[^\\]+)+\.\w+  a file path
|                          OR
\S+                        any group of non whitespace characters
```

The trick here is to eagerly try to match a file path first.  Only that failing do we try to match one word/term at a time.